# Weird Normal Lines Glitch

Tags: edit-mode, normals, subdivision-surface

When viewing face normals as lines + Subdivision modifier + toggling Subdivision cage, there's a weird glitch where the face normal lines appear in random locations / shapes:

[image]

https://youtu.be/aA-IgXhRU8E

Happening in 2.90 and 2.91.2

Any ideas what might be causing this?